# Git rev-list command gives different result on different time

Tags: git

I am running this command on my local git command line (git version 2.0.1) with IST (GMT+5:30) timezone:

```
git rev-list --after=2016-03-10 --before=2016-03-11 --all --format='%H, %cd, %aE'
```

Running this command at different time `9:00 am IST`, `1:00 PM IST`, `6:00 PM IST` gives me different results.

Can anybody explain how before and after works in git-revlist command?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently git treats "2016-03-10" in date as "2016-03-10 of current time", so it precise meaning depends on when you run it. I'm trying it now, at 8:44 local time, and can see for example commit made at 09:32, but not at 08:21

To avoid uncertainty, use exact date with time: --after="2016-30-10 00:00:00"